# exiting app when press back , and mixing up scenes when back to previous scene

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an android app using AS3 Flash CS5.5 , is just a simple photo gallery to photos that were uploaded to a web page , I have to Scenes:

Scene 1 is a welcomeing scnen with button leads to scene 2
Scene 2 is the gallery scene..

i'm using this code , and it is working well , but when I press BACK key at the device , first it exits from the app , and when I open the app again it send me to scene 2 is mixed up with scene 2 O.o .. so it's like it came back to scene 1 but it keeps the contents of scene 2 above the contents of scene 1 ..

so what can I do to stop exiting the app when pressing BACK key at the device ??
and what should I do to stop the problem of the BACK key , and write the correct code that send me back to the first scene ...

and thaaaanks a lot :))

```
    var pictureArray:Array = new Array;
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

    stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame);

    var loader1 = new Loader();
    loader1.load(new URLRequest("MYURL"));
    pictureArray.push(loader1);

    var loader2 = new Loader();
    loader2.load(new URLRequest("MYURL"));
    pictureArray.push(loader2);


    addChild(pictureArray[0]);
    pictureArray[0].x = 0; pictureArray[0].y = 0; 


    var n:int = 0;                                  

    function fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
    {
        if(event.offsetX == 1)
        {
      removeChild(pictureArray[n]);
      n = n+1; 


      if (n>pictureArray.length - 1)
        n=0;

      addChild(pictureArray[n]);
      pictureArray[n].x = 0; pictureArray[n].y = 0; 
         }
        else if(event.offsetX == -1)
        {
      removeChild(pictureArray[n]);
      n = n-1;
      if (n<0)
        n=pictureArray.length - 1;

      addChild(pictureArray[n]);
      pictureArray[n].x = 0; pictureArray[n].y = 0; 
         }
    }

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, CheckKeypress, false, 0, true)

function CheckKeypress(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    switch (event.keyCode) 
    { 
        case Keyboard.BACK: 
        gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");
        break;  
        } 
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you completely exit the app when the back is pressed?

Comment: this is why I'm asking ,,,
I don't want it to exit !!!

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood. So if you press back from scene 2 you want to go to scene 1 instead of exiting?

Comment: it's ok ....
yes exactly , that's what i'm looking for ,,, I want it to go back to scene 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function android_backUp(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
  switch (e.keyCode)
  {
    case Keyboard.BACK :
    e.preventDefault();
    // YOUR CODE
    break;
  }
}
```